# UITableViewの特定セクションの特定のCellを特定条件で隠したい

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

下記のソースコードでセクション全てを隠すことはできましたが、
セクション1内の特定のセルだけを隠したいです。
iOSに明るくないため、方法を知っている方がいましたらよろしくお願いします。

隠す条件はCellのテキストで判断しようと思っています。
Cellの中にはContentViewがあり、左右にラベルが配置してあります。
ストーリーボードのstatic cellを使用しています。

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {    // セクション1内セルをすべて非表示
        cell.hidden = YES;
    }
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {    // セクション1内のセルの高さをすべて０に
        return 0;
    } else {
        return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

Comment: 隠したセルは画面操作（ボタン押下等）で再度表示される想定でしょうか？もし、基本的には表示対象外なのであればdatasource（表示対象の要素）から除外してしまうのも有りかと思います。

Comment: 再度表示することはありませんが、iOSのバージョンによって表示したいセルと隠したいセルがあります。

とりあえずcellを取得して、テキストの内容を判断するところまでできましたので、なんとかできそうです。

Comment: なるほど、承知しました。もしできましたら自己回答（+ベストアンサー）をしていただけるとありがたいです（他の方の助けになりますので）。吉報お待ちしています。

Comment: 自己回答になりましたが、書いておきました！

Comment: ありがとうございます、賛成投票させていただきました！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

viewDidLoadで消したいセルのテキストは空文字列にしておく。

以下は、セルの中のcontentViewに二つラベルがあり、右側が空文字列だったら消す処理です。

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell 

*)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 1) { // セクション1内のセルが対象
        UILabel *l = (UILabel*)cell.contentView.subviews[1];
        NSString *str = l.text;
        if([str length] == 0){  // このセルが空文字列だったら隠す
            cell.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {  // セクション1内のセルが対象

        UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UILabel *l = (UILabel*)cell.contentView.subviews[1];
        NSString *str = l.text;
        if([str length] == 0){  // このセルが空文字列だったら隠す
            return 0;
        }

        return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    } else {
        return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```