# UITableViewで特定のCellを非表示にしたい。

Tags: ios, uitableview

下記の様に書くと、cellが元々あった場所はそのまま確保されていて、backgroundが露出してしまいます。
非表示にしたcellがあった場所は上詰めで下のcellが上がって欲しいです。

```
[_targetCell  setHidden:YES];
[[self tableView] reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0xfffffff7さんの解答を元に解決しました。cellがhiddenならheightを0にしました。

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [_targetCell  setHidden:YES];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  if( cell.hidden ){
    return 0;

  } else {
    return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

自分が以前に自己解決した質問を載せておきます。

[UITableViewの特定セクションの特定のCellを特定条件で隠したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6956/uitableview%E3%81%AE%E7%89%B9%E5%AE%9A%E3%82%BB%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E7%89%B9%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%AEcell%E3%82%92%E7%89%B9%E5%AE%9A%E6%9D%A1%E4%BB%B6%E3%81%A7%E9%9A%A0%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84/6959#6959)

Answer (score 0):

内部的には非表示処理でも、`UITableView`上では削除として扱うべきかと。
なので`UITableViewDataSource`の行を削除状態にしてから`deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`を呼べばいいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

これは、Q1 セルの存在条件が無くなったのか? Q2 Q1がyesなら、なぜ、datasourceは、それを反映できないのか? Q3　Q1がNoだが、あえてそのセルを非表示にしたいのか？

のquestionに回答できないと、正確な解答はできないと思います。
Q1:No Q3:Yes なら、Collapsible TableViewのたぐいの操作が必要なんじゃないかと。
Collapsible TableViewは、Appleから、TV Animations and Gestures という有名なサンプルコードが出ています。結構、面倒くさいですが。